# Getting the percentage of a color in an image using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, colors

So I have this python script that detects and print a range of HSV color in an image but i want to add another functionality to it.

It want it to be able to print the percentage of that color.

My Script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Vishu Rana/Documents/PY/test_cases/image.jpg')


grid_RGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plt.imshow(grid_RGB) # Printing the original picture after converting to RGB


grid_HSV = cv2.cvtColor(grid_RGB, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV) # Converting to HSV
lower_green = np.array([25,52,72])
upper_green = np.array([102,255,255])

mask= cv2.inRange(grid_HSV, lower_green, upper_green)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask) # Generating image with the green part

print("Green Part of Image")
plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plt.imshow(res)
```

What do i need to add in this code to make it also print the percentage of green color.

Comment: Percentage of green pixels in the mask? Something like: `np.sum(mask) / np.size(mask)`.

Comment: @Benjamin will this return the percentage of green pixels in the original image.

Comment: I assumed it was a binary/boolean mask. But you know what they say about assuming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV arrays create a mask that uses the value 255.  A simple way to get the percentage of green is simply implement the following code after you generate the mask.

```
    green_perc = (mask>0).mean()
```

A more thorough explanation was asked about why this works.  When OpenCV creates a mask it will create a 2 dimensional array with values of 0s and values of 255.  In the context of this question the values of 255 are the parts of the mask that indicate the picture is green.

The reason that (mask>0).mean() works is because we only have values of 255 and 0.  Mask > 0 will create a boolean array of True/False for every value in our mask.

The value True will indicate that the part of the array is green and the value of False will indicate it is not green.  Taking the mean of this boolean array will give us the percentage of the array that is green.  (when taking the mean of a boolean array True will take the value of 1 and False will take the value of 0).

Another way to get the same result is to implement code like this.

```
green_perc = (mask==255).mean()
```

A comment above also mentions the solution of np.sum(mask)/np.size(mask).  This does not work right because OpenCV uses the value 255.  You could tweak this to get the same percentage by dividing this value by 255.

```
green_perc = (np.sum(mask) / np.size(mask))/255
```

Comment: the above comment gives out 10.155619855967078 and your solution gives 0.03982596021947874.

Comment: @VishuRana the comment is wrong, the percentage cannot be above 1.0, the code in the comment sums up the values of 255 instead of summing up 1 for every pixel. hence the wrong result.

Comment: @VishuRana I have no idea, you have the image. does the image have 3.98% of green in your calculated mask? the calculations in the answer seem correct, but I don't know how you apply them.

Comment: @VishuaRana Since OpenCV arrays use 255 for the mask, summing and dividing by size is going to give you a number that is too high.  This is why I am looking for where the array is >0.  If you divide the number you got from the comment by 255 you should come to the solution that i gave as well.

Comment: @lenik im linking the image. Can you also confirm [link](https://imgur.com/a/X7uN4zs) . I think it is right

Comment: @lenik can you explain the "mask>0" part. what is going on there. Or explain the whole - "(mask>0).mean()"

Comment: @jawsem can you explain the "mask>0" part. what is going on there. Or explain the whole - "(mask>0).mean()"

Comment: Hi Vishu, your mask is an array of values of 0 or 255 according to the OpenCV docs.  I say mask > 0 because i am looking for all values in the mask that are greater than 0 and then the mean part is taking the average of all those values.  You can accomplish the same thing by doing (mask==255).mean().  I will add some additional detail and examples to help explain it to my initial solution.